# Why doesn't `sys.modules.keys()` include name from `import...as`?

Tags: python

Say I import a module as follows:

```
import os as OSMOD
```

and then wanted to find the working directory

```
OSMOD.getcwd()
```

`OSMOD` is now a stand in for `os`, and using `os` won't work.  This is all dandy, and works for me. However, I noticed something a little odd.  If I import `os` as I do above, and then get a list of all imported modules, here's what happens:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os as OSMOD
>>> modList = sys.modules.keys()
>>> print "os" in modList
True
>>> print "OSMOD" in modList
False
```

This is not what I expected.  According to the docs `modules.keys() only lists the imported modules`.  To me, this means it should list `OSMOD`.

Why doesn't `sys.modules.keys()` contain `OSMOD` instead of `os`?

Additionally, is there an equivalent list to `sys.modules.keys()` which would contain `OSMOD`?

**EDIT:** I guess the larger question here is the rationale.  If Python is going to keep `os` as the module, why delete the reference? (ie, why don't both `os.getcwd()` and `OSMOD.getcwd()` work?)

Or, more simply put, why doesn't `import os as OSMOD` behave the same as `import os` followed by `OSMOD = os`?

Comment: OSMOD is in ``globals()``.

Comment: *why doesn't import os as OSMOD behave the same as import os followed by OSMOD = os?*: Because you don't want to pollute the global namespace of your module with names you are not going to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the module *object* and the references to that object. `sys.modules['os']` is *one* reference to the module object, and `OSMOD` is another.

When you use the statement `import os as OSMOD`, Python makes sure the `os` module is loaded into memory (using the `sys.modules` dictionary as a cache) then creates a reference to the module object in your current namespace. Because you used `as OSMOD` Python sees that you want to use the name `OSMOD` and binds the module to that name.

Had you used `import os`, then Python would have defaulted to the same name as the module, so it binds the object to `os` in your local namespace.

You are in no way restricted here. You can still bind the same object to *other* names too:

```
os = OSMOD
```

would give you another reference to the same module object.

Remember that your module global namespace is only global to the module; other modules don't see the same names. As such you want to control what names are defined in it. Perhaps you wanted use the name `os` for something *else* entirely. The following is legal:

```
os = 'Ozzy Santana'
import os as OSMOD
```

and I would expect `os` to still be bound to the string, not the module.

At the same time, another module in my Python project can still use `import os` and have `os` refer to the module; it won't see the string bound to `os` in the first module.

Answer (score 9):

Because the name of the module is `os`. You did `import os`. `as OSMOD` just tells Python to assign that module to the name `OSMOD` *in your module's namespace.*

`sys.modules` is a cache of imported modules to prevent modules from being imported more than once. If it stored the imported module under `OSMOD`, another module that did `import os` would import the module again.

Comment: Right, but then Python should recognize ```os``` just the same since that module was imported

Comment: What Python "should" do is what it is documented as doing. Which is: first, it imports the module `os`. If you specify a name using the `as` clause, it then assigns the module to that name in your module's namespace. Otherwise it assigns the module into your namespace under its actual name. Think of `import` as an assignment.

Comment: @wnnmaw: no, because `import` **binds** the imported module to a name of your choosing.

Comment: @wnnmaw: if you want `os` to work, don't use a different name. Use `import os` to bind to the same name as the module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't want it to work, but it seems strange that Python keeps ```os``` in memory, but restricts how its accessed.

Comment: @wnnmaw Python didn't restrict that. You did :)

Comment: @wnnmaw: No, you are misunderstanding how Python names work. A module is an object, just like anything else. Names merely refer to the object. You can still do `os = OSMOD` and access `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, of course, that's why I asked the question!  But I don't see the rationale for why.  If I do ```imoprt os``` and then ```OSMOD = os```, I can use both.  But ```import...as``` includes an extra ```del os```.

Comment: @wnnmaw: It doesn't do any `del os` because `os` was never bound in your local namespace.

Comment: @wnnmaw: **all** names in your global namespace are local to your module only. They are not global across all modules in the interpreter. As such, you can name modules anything you like, and that is helpful to avoid name clashes.

Comment: @wnnmaw: By using `import os as OSMOD` you are now free to use `os = somethingelse`.

Comment: @wnnmaw: But another module can still use `import os` and use the exact same methods contained within the `os` module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Ok! Those last two did it!

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) contains the true names of the imported modules.  However, it does *not* contain the names they were imported under using `as <name>`.

In other words, when you do:

```
import os as OSMOD
```

the `os` module is in fact imported.  However, it is imported under the name of `OSMOD`.

Nevertheless, the name `os` is still added to `sys.modules` because that is the true name of the imported module.  `OSMOD` though is *not* added because it is not a module.  Instead, it is an alternate name for the `os` module that was imported.

Comment: But ```type(OSMOD)``` returns ```<type 'module'>```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
>
> - find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
> - define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs.

In particular, the second step means:

> If the requested module is retrieved successfully, it will be made available in the local namespace in one of three ways:
>
> - If the module name is followed by as, then the name following as is bound directly to the imported module.

This implies that the name under which your module is available will be present in `locals()` or `globals()`:

```
>>>import sys as X
>>> locals()['X']
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported `os`. Then you put it to the name `OSMOD`. Here is a simple illustration of what's happening:

```
import os
OSMOD = os
del os
```

The module imported is still `os`, not `osmod`, so it will be the one listed in `sys.modules.keys()`.

And yes, `type(OSMOD)` is a module since it's bound to a module object.